# VSExpress and Resource Editing/XAML Designer/MFC/ATL

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc, rc

I recently succeeded in installing Visual Studio 2015 on a computer since my laptop always fails in installing. I have a few questions about the VS series and the product inside:

1. Is lower "edition" of VS (of same version) faster or takes less memory in running the IDE (e.g. "2015 Express" vs "2015 Community" vs "2015 Ultimate")? Will the file compiled by them have big performance difference (like optimization)?
2. Is it possible to use "some method" (like mounting/umounting, change disk letter, sandbox or backup some file) to install Community and Enterprise (both 2015) at the same time? I didn't buy the Enterprise edition, but I still want to try the "perfect" version (which seems much better than Community at https://www.visualstudio.com/products/compare-visual-studio-2015-products-vs). I don't know when the Enterprise version will refuse working. Since Community is free, I'd like to keep both (and maybe get familiar with the difference of two version).
3. In VS2015 Express for Desktop, is it possible to use MFC/ATL wizard/template (is that function "disabled" or "not included")? I know I can use MFC/ATL headers by simply including them directly.
4. In VS2015 Express for Desktop, I googled and found out that resource editing isn't there for Express. Can it somehow "link" to the Resource Editing function in "Community"? I'm afraid that those third party resource editor are "outdated" and can somebody recommend a good one?
5. Is Windows Forms Designer for WinForm, and XAML Designer for WPF/Sliverlight/WinRT? And since resource editing isn't there for "Express", MFC/ATL/WTL application won't have "XXX Designer" (except third party software)? Does WinForm/WPF/Sliverlight/WinRT need resource editing? (By resource editing, I would care more about the "drag" part (aka DIALOG and widgits)
6. This is a general question about windows GUI programming (not graphics like Open* and Direct*). I read some article and it said that the general "evolution" is Win16 API -> Win32 API -> MFC/ATL/WTL -> WinForm -> WPF/Sliverlight/WinRT. Is there more to add or something to fix (since the article is written 2 years ago)? Is there another API for 64bit windows or for Win10? How about other tools/programming language I can refer to like Delphi/Java/QT? Do I need to briefly know them all in order to be "experienced" or just use one of them and all else are "outdated"?
7. I really like the "inline" way of writing GUI code. Something like:

   **auto w=Window(SomeLayoutClass(xxx),Button(xxx).OnClick(someFunction),Box(SomeLayoutClass(xxx),xxx)).Size(xxx,xxx).Show()**

   Is there any API in C/C++ (or C#) working like this?

Comment: Free version of Visual Studio has resource editor, MFC/ATL, etc. If you are a large corporation you are required to pay for it, otherwise you can use the free version. The rest of your question is off topic. You should ask programming questions, one question at a time.

Comment: If you have to ask those question, you will not benefit from the *Enterprise* edition. Get Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition and move on. There's nothing you will be missing. As for your final question: Get into the habit of writing code that can be debugged. Once you join a team, your co-workers may value that **a lot**.